# Trying to rotate an object for every x frames using python

Tags: python

What I have tried is this:

```
def my_handler(scene):
    if C.scene.frame_current % 24 == 0:
         obj.rotation_euler = [0, math.radians(20), 0]
```

The script compiles but does not work as expected in the blender viewport. The object remains not rotating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I need to see more code.  What is `obj` set to?  Why isn't it passed in, like `scene`?  With `scene` passed in, why are you using `C.scene` rather than `scene`? Do you want keyframes?  Should the rotation be instantaneous?

But your main problem is that using `rotation_euler` that way doesn't *increment* the rotation, it sets it 20 degrees and leaves it there.  So once every 24 frames you're setting the rotation to a specific value.

If you want to *increment *20 degrees every 24 frames, you need something like `math.radians(scene.frame_current * 20 / 24)`.

maybe recode your function to something like this?

```py
def my_handler(scene, obj):
    if scene.frame_current % 24 == 0:
        inc = scene.frame_current / 24
        r = inc * 20
        obj.rotation_euler = [0, math.radians(r), 0]
        # Do you want to add a keyframe here?
        # uncomment the next line if so
        # obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame=scene.frame_current)
```

But if you're trying to set keyframes every 24 frames there's an easier way to do it:

```py
for i in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end, 24):
    r = int(i/24) * 20
    obj.rotation_euler = [0, math.radians(r), 0]
    obj.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame=scene.frame_current)
```

You can, of course replace `scene.frame_start` and `scene.frame_end` with whatever values you want to use for the start and end of the animation.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize my original question was missing so much information. I wasn't looking to keyframe it, but you answered my question regardless. Also, if we wanted to increment the rotation by a certain value, x for example, couldn't we just get the data of the rotation and add x each time? Like:
obj.rotation_euler[1] = bpy.data.obj.rotation_euler[1] + radians(20)
With obj being set to an object within the scene.

Comment: Yes you could do it by incrementing each time.  I'm not sure why I picked redoing the calculation for my examples -- adding is faster.  But be aware that since you're rotating by Euler rather than Quaternion, you might find the object turning in different directions as it passes through 360/0 degrees.

Comment: I think I've just ran into that issue. I added a new question similar to what you've said, perhaps you can help with that one?